Redirecting from a server component in NextJS
In my NextJS project, I have a route ("/dashboard") which is a server component and from that I want to make user redirect to home page ("/") based on some conditions but I am not getting success.
I have tried in several ways but nothing is working:
Here is the code inside page.js:
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const page = async () => {
  const token = cookies().get("token");
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token.value, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
    console.log(decoded);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    //! First Approach
    const baseUrl = "http://localhost:3000";
    const url = new URL("/", baseUrl);
    return NextResponse.redirect(url);
    //! Second Approach
    // const baseUrl = "http://localhost:3000";
    // const url = new URL("/", baseUrl);
    // redirect(url);
    //! Third Approach
    // redirect("/");
  }
  return <div></div>;
};

export default page;

Sometime it is throwing me an error or doing nothing, but it is not redirecting me at all. could anyone please help me to redirect from a server component?

just import redirectimport { redirect } from 'next/navigation' and run redirect("/")


In NextJs, the redirect function throws a particular error that has to be handled by the next itself. Because of that, we have to move the redirect outside of the try-catch in order to pass that error to the NextJS

try {
}
catch (e){
}
redirect("/home")

In successful scenario
 const redirectFunction = async () => {
    try {
      redirect('/home');
    } catch (error) {
      if (isRedirectError(error)) {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  };

For error scenario, you can use this workaround
let success=false;
try{
  await fetch();
  success=true;
}
catch(error){
  redirect(error_page);
}
finally{
 if (success){
    redirect(success_page);
  }
}

source for error scenario
source

He is asking why the redirect is not working; the redirect is not working because it's inside the catch block; that's what the video clip explains.
